# getting error in comparing 2 dataset values through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dataset

am having 2 dataset. named as ds, ds1. dataset value contain value like this

```
dataset(values from excel sheet)
--------
no  phone       title
91  9942321400  MR
91  9865015695  MR
91  9677031515  MR
91  9994828285  MR
91  9688104229  MR


dataset1 contain value like this(values from mysql table)
-------------------------------
phone
9942321400
9865015695
9677031515
```

compare 2 datset. if dataset are not equal to datset1 phone , we have to write that dataset phone no in  notepad.but am getting wrong result.

```
mycode

Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (i <= ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
            Dim phone As String = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
            Dim j As Integer = 0
            Do While (j <= Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
                Dim dumphone As String = Ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item(4).ToString
                If (dumphone <> phone) Then
                    TextBox1.AppendText(a.ToString & "|" & b.ToString & "|" & c.ToString)
                    sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                End If
                j = (j + 1)
                'i = i + 1
            Loop
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
```

my result in notepad

---

```
|91|9942321400|MR
|91|9942321400|MR
|91|9942321400|MR
|91|9942321400|MR
|91|9865015695|MR
|91|9865015695|MR
|91|9865015695|MR
|91|9865015695|MR
|91|9677031515|MR
|91|9677031515|MR
|91|9677031515|MR
|91|9677031515|MR    


but expected output in notepad like this
----------------------------------------
91|9994828285|MR
91|9688104229|MR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is comparing each line of the second dataset vs each line in the first.

Your Do While blocks go through the entire thing, there is no exclusion code for it.

So in your example, the first number it compares is dumphone(0) = 9942321400 It matches the first time it goes through the Do While when phone(0) = 9942321400. But then your Do While is still going. When it hits the second number, dumphone(1) = 9865015695, it doesn't match, so you get your output line.

Here's one option of how you could get the desired output

```
Dim toggle as Boolean = false
Do While (i <= ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
        Dim phone As String = ds1.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Do While (j <= Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
            Dim dumphone As String = Ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item(4).ToString
            If dumphone = phone Then toggle = true 'This will set your flag to add the output.
            j = (j + 1)
        Loop
            'After we're done checking if there's a match, we decided to add it to the output.
            If toggle = true Then
                TextBox1.AppendText(a.ToString & "|" & b.ToString & "|" & c.ToString)
                sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                toggle = false 'Reset the flag for the next value
            End If
            i = (i + 1) 'Move to the next value to check against.
    Loop
```

Comment: already am specified my expected result. but am getting the result in notepad phone numbers one by one like this9942321400,9865015695,9677031515

Comment: am not getting the correct result. which line i have to change get my expected result already i specified.

Answer (score 1):

I think, You need to compare both the data set and the numbers common to both should not appear in your text box.

if numbers are equal then set a flag, and if that flag is not set then only write the value to the textbox.